# Error running application using EF 7 after adding dependencies and updating model classes

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am running MVC 6 and EF 7 and have changed my models and wish to run the application, however I receive an error and it is not clear what the root cause is.

below is a snippet from my project.json

```
"dependencies": {
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery": "1.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5"
},
```

Below is the web page  error.

> System.MissingMethodException
>   Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.TryAdd(Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor).
>       at Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services) 
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildHostingServices() 
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build() 
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.RuntimeHttpApplication.ApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application) 
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.InvokeApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been a lot of breaking changes from one beta version to another.

Because of that I suggest you to align all versions in your `project.json` to either beta5 or beta6.

Comment: I agree with that, but I don't get to select beta 5 for antiforgery using nuget or editing the project.json directly, can you tell me the best way to go about making them all beta 5 or beta 6.

Comment: [AntiForgery was added in beta6](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/34). Considering that I think it's best to just update everything to beta6. For now I update my packages just searching and replacing in ``project.json``, VS will take care of the rest.

Comment: Yes, but if  I upgrade to 6 the visual studio generated authentication classes will be out of sync, so probably need to have them updated locally before generating the project with authentication?

Comment: Solution was to install beta 6, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48222

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot this option. For everyone else reading: ASP.NET 5 will change a lot in the next couple of months so some breaking changes are still possible. To always get up do speed see the ASP.NET 5 [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) and subscribe to the [announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements) repository.

Comment: My project did not have EF still same error and same solution. Aligned beta5 with MVC6 and its dependencies.